# Error in javascript jsPDF Library Order Elements

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to create PDF documents, the problem is that I want the order of the view when starting the page, but when downloading the generated document, all the elements are mounted and out of order.

In the creation of the document I put them in order, but it is also messy, is there a way to order the html elements without mounting? I am totally new to this library, what am I doing wrong?

This code generates the preview I want and automatically downloads the generated document(I have disabled it, because I show a picture of the problem), which is messy and I don't know how to fix it.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Test</title>

   <style>
     #output {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       margin-top: 20px;
     }

     #my-table {
       border: solid 1px #565656;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       font-family: helvetica,serif;
       font-size: 10pt;
       width: 180mm;
     }

     #my-table th {
       border: solid 1px #565656;
       background-color: #9a7f5b;
       color: #eee;
       text-align: left;
       padding: 5px;
     }

     #my-table td {
       border: solid 1px #565656;
       padding: 2px 5px;
     }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <!--ELEMENTS PDF-->
   <h1 id="title">This is a test</h1>
   <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis natus ipsa sit ab ipsum illum vero dolore velit impedit debitis itaque aut, magni ut laborum ratione esse? Beatae, omnis excepturi.</p>
   <table id="my-table">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th colspan="2">Name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Country</th>
         <th>Activity</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Donna</td>
         <td>Moore</td>
         <td>Example.com</td>
         <td>China</td>
         <td>Work</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>Janice</td>
         <td>Henry</td>
         <td>Example.com</td>
         <td>Ukraine</td>
         <td>Eat</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>Ruth</td>
         <td>Wells</td>
         <td>Example.com</td>
         <td>Mexico</td>
         <td>Run</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>Jason</td>
         <td>Ray</td>
         <td>Example.com</td>
         <td>Brazil</td>
         <td>Commute</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>Jane</td>
         <td>Stephens</td>
         <td>Example.com</td>
         <td>United States</td>
         <td>Watch TV</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>6</td>
         <td>Adam</td>
         <td>Nichols</td>
         <td>Example.com</td>
         <td>Canada</td>
         <td>Sleep</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   <div id="piechart" style="width: 600px; height: 300px; margin: 35px 0px 0px 40px;"></div>
<!--^ ELEMENTS PDF ^-->
  
   <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}
     ).then(function () {

      //Google Charts
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
         ['Work',     11],
         ['Eat',      2],
         ['Commute',  2],
         ['Watch TV', 2],
         ['Sleep',    7]
       ]);

       var chartpie = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
       chartpie.draw(data);


       //------------------jsPDF ------------------

       const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm')

       //ELEMENTS HTML
       var title = document.getElementById('title');
       var text = document.getElementById('text');

       //CREATE DOCUMENT
      doc.fromHTML(title);
      doc.fromHTML(text);

       doc.autoTable({
           html: '#my-table',
           theme: 'grid',
       })

       
       doc.addImage(chartpie.getImageURI(), 0, 0);
       //doc.save('example.pdf');

     });
     
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Output error image, messy and mounted items,this is how the pdf document comes out.
[image: Error]

Comment: @KJ Thank you very much, there is a picture to better understand the problem, I use Microsoft Edge and the document comes out like this.

Comment: @KJ ..so the problem is from the jspdf sheet format?

Comment: @KJ Thank you very much for the help, I finally discovered a solution, it was to change the version, I searched exhaustively and it would never be able to be fixed because the versions of the CDN that I use are incompatible with the documentation, in short, I changed the version and I was able to order all the document, I really appreciate your help!